# How to get animation to play multiple times in Unity?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I want to get a sprite to play an animation of a drop of liquid falling every time that it is clicked, however the animation only plays the first time I click it and I have no idea why.

Here is the code used on the sprite:

```
public class PipetteScript : MonoBehaviour {

public Animator pipetteAnim;
public BoxCollider2D pipetteMove;
public IndicatorScript indicator;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    pipetteAnim.enabled = true;
    pipetteMove.enabled = true;
    indicator.enabled = true;
}

void OnMouseDown () {
    pipetteAnim.Play ("Pipette_dropping");
    Debug.Log ("Anim playing");
    }
}
```

The debug log even prints out "Anim playing" every time I click on the sprite.

Answer (score 0):

Use animation in Update function and Let me update

```
public class PipetteScript : MonoBehaviour {
public Animator pipetteAnim;
public BoxCollider2D pipetteMove;
public IndicatorScript indicator;
public bool boolval = false;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    pipetteAnim.enabled = true;
    pipetteMove.enabled = true;
    indicator.enabled = true;
}
void update()
{
 if(boolval == true)
   pipetteAnim.Play ("Pipette_dropping");
 if(boolval == false)
   pipetteAnim.Stop ("Pipette_dropping");
}
void OnMouseDown () {
    boolval = True;
    }
void OnMouseUp () {
    boolval = False;
    }
```

Comment: I can't use .Stop for a variable of type Animator.

Comment: then use SetBool like,   `pipetteAnim.SetBool("Pipette_dropping",false);`

Comment: SetBool wasn't working either, I had to use a trigger instead ans that got it working.